Protect Raspberry PI from L298N's power source
I would like to build an RC car and I would like to use a Raspberry PI 4 and an L298N. I attached screenshots how the wiring looks like now.
Everything is working fine, it is working now but I am little bit afraid because I would like to use a 5V power bank for the RaspberryPI and a 12V battery for the L298N as power source.
I don't know what will happen if the power bank runs out and the Rasperry  shut down but there will be still voltage from the 12V battery. Can it harm the Raspberry PI? If yes, can you help me how can I avoid it?




If it were me, I'd shorten and tint the leads on those binding post wires. It looks like it would be too easy to accidentally short a few of them together. True, you shouldn't back drive logic circuit inputs. But, generally, that leads to unexpected behavior more then permanent damage. Question: Are you sure you need or want an RPi in an embedded situation? An RPi running a version of Linux is likely running dozens and dozens of programs at a given moment. Most of which you likely don't need (Printer servers? Ethernet drivers?). Because of this there may be mil-sec response time variations.

What makes you think it needs "protecting" and from what?

@st2000 Thank you for your hint, I will look after the wiring and correct it. Regarding to you second hint, I have only Raspberry PI and I am only learning it. :) Later I would like to also add some sensors and camera. But do you have any suggestions what should I use instead?

@Milliways Thank you for your answer. I am afraid of that the 12V battery can damage my Raspberry PI if the Raspberry PI is not connected to any power source. Can it be a problem? Or shouldn't I worry about it?

I think it best if you read up on the difference between a Single Board Computer (like a Raspberry Pi) and an Embedded Processor (like an Arduino). It would be hard to describe the difference here in the comments. If you are adding video then stick w/the Raspberry Pi. Also, if you don't need to generate precisely timed wave forms, a Raspberry Pi can interface with sensors. That said, it is undesirable to remove power from a Raspberry Pi (or most any SBC) w/o shutting it down 1st. To do so runs the chance of corrupting the SDCard. In some cases, preventing the SBC from booting up again.

Presumably the unspecified device you are using only has logic level inputs so 12V shouldn't get anywhere near the Pi. You haven't said what is actually connected, so this is only a guess. I would be more worried about damage from the terrible wiring.

@st2000  "An RPi running a version of Linux is likely running dozens and dozens of programs at a given moment." -> That's not true.  It is likely there are (on a minimal headless system) a few dozen process extant, but that is not the same thing as "running".  They just occupy memory until they need to do something, which for something like a print server is pretty much never unless you are printing things (and ethernet drivers are part of the kernel, they do not operate in user space as a program, but running programs may make use of them).

...A degree of variable latency vs. a microcontroller is a reality, but this is mostly because there is a multitasking OS kernel running (and if anything is running, it is too).  It only takes two running programs for the scheduler to be actively time slicing, which is when the most significant latency occurs.  However, again, on a minimal system dedicated to only one or two active tasks, this is generally not a show stopper, depending on the task. It certainly wouldn't matter WRT controlling the speed/direction of a car motor. I'm sure there are oodles of RC vehicles out there with Pi brains.

If you are planning to use a power bank DON'T. They are designed to charge batteries NOT provide a stable 5V power source and ofter have poor regulation.
You would be better to use a buck converter to generate 5V from your 12V battery which is likely to be cheaper and certainly smaller.

Thank you for your answer. Can you give me some example what should I use exactly?

It appears you are asking a shopping question. There are hundreds of different buck converters - readily available. UBEC are high quality units often used for model aeroplanes.
